# Moving the github repo that's a bower package

Tags: github, bower

So I have a bower package `famous-material` at https://github.com/StephanBijzitter/Famous-Material

I want to move this repository to: github.com/Skelware/Famous-Material, but I'm afraid I'll break things to the point where I cannot fix them. How would I do this?

To clarify, the ideal intention is to do the following, but if that's not possible I'd be okay with other solutions, of course:

- Migrate the Famous-Material repository from StephanBijzitter to Skelware
- While making sure the bower package famous-material is not going to be stuck at StephanBijzitter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you might need to unregister the bower package:

```
bower unregister <package>
```

(Actually, the [issue 120](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/120) mentioned also the curl command, if the package is hosted on GitHub and you're an owner or collaborator:

```
curl -X DELETE "https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/PACKAGE?access_token=TOKEN"
```

)

See also "[**bower/registry: Unregister package**](https://github.com/bower/registry#unregister-package)"

---

If you are a member of the Skelware organization, you could simply create a new (empty) repo Famous-Material, and, from your current local clone, do a:

```
git remote add Skelware https://myLogin@github.com/Skelware/Famous-Material
git push --mirror Skelware
```

Then delete your [first GitHub repo](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/) and [register/create your new package](https://github.com/bower/registry#create-package).

Comment: Hmm, but that would leave Famous-Material at StephanBijzitter too, right? Ideally I'd fully migrate to Skelware.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter you can delete your GitHub repo once the migration is complete. (https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/)

Comment: Ah, I assumed it had to be kept alive to keep the mirror at Skelware alive. But then the bower package would still break, correct?

Comment: @StephanBijzitter once the push is done, both repos are completely independent and you can remove the first one. But you need to update the bower package reference indeed.

Comment: Any chance you also know how to do that? :P

Comment: @StephanBijzitter possibly with https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/120. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Seems I had issues removing the package so I just posted on the issue to let them do it for me. The repository was successfully moved, thanks for the help!